# Incorrect assertion in junit / mockito

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

There is testing method:

```
public boolean isFoo(SomeObj someObj) {
        if(someObj != null) {
            return bean.filter(someObj.getValue()) || (!bean.filter(someObj.getValue()) && !someObj.isParameter());
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and there is test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OtherBeanTest{

    @Mock
    private OtherBean otherBean ;

    @Mock
    private Bean bean;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj().value("value").parameter(false);

        when(bean.filter(anyString())).thenReturn(false);

        System.out.println(otherBean.isFoo(someObj));
        System.out.println(bean.filter(someObj.getValue()) || (!bean.filter(someObj.getValue()) && !someObj.isParameter()));

        Assert.assertTrue(otherBean.isFoo(someObj));
    }
```

The problem is that assertion returns error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at OtherBeanTest.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

While printLine return respectively false and true, but it's incorrect. Where's the problem?

Also, I'v got problem with my Intellij Idea - it skipping set breakpoints inside mocking class and I don't know why.

Comment: Where did you put the breakpoint in your code?

Comment: On any line inside isFoo() method

Comment: Could you show us the SomeObj isParameter method?

Comment: `private boolean parameter;

    public boolean isParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }`

Comment: Where do u get `bean` from inside of the `isFoo` method? It isn't the `bean` you've mocked in your tests, you never inject it.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `otherBean` is just a mock and you call `isFoo()` on a mock without telling it to return any specific value. The default value returned by a boolean returning method is `false`.

I'm not sure what your plans were but I don't think that is what you tried to do.

If you intended to test `OtherBean` then you need an actual object and inject mocks of the dependencies. It could look something like this:

```
public class OtherBeanTest{

  @Mock
  private Bean bean;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    SomeObj someObj = new SomeObj().value("value").parameter(false);

    when(bean.filter(anyString())).thenReturn(false);
    OtherBean otherBean = new OtherBean();
    otherBean.setBean(bean);

    Assert.assertTrue(otherBean.isFoo(someObj));
  }
}
```